# I can't edit a node content into an XML file with Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to edit an XML file with Java, the thing is that I need to edit the content & replace them by what I want inside

(I want to replace some nodes that are in Deutsh into French

[for expample `<fr>DE1</fr>` into `<fr>FR1</fr>`])

I tried to use :

```
node.setTextContent(Value);
node.setNodeValue(Value);
```

But it doesn't work at all
Is there any other function that might work in editing these nodes below ?

Here's the code :

```
            for (int i = memory; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(i);
                if ((langu.equals(node.getNodeName())))   //langu = "fr"
                {
                test = node.getTextContent();
                    if(isCorrect()){}

                    else if ((manualTr.clickCount >= 0)  
                            ){
                            trash = test;
                            node.setTextcontent(Value);
                    //      node.setNodeValue("Test");
                            memory += manualTr.clickCount;
                            manualTr.clickCount -= 1;
                    }
                }
                }
```

And here's the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<titles>
    <tome>
       <de>DE1</de>
       <fr>DE1</fr>
       <en>EN1</en>
    </tome>
    <valhalla>
       <de>DE2</de>
       <fr>DE2</fr>
       <en>EN2</en>
    </valhalla>
    <vikings>
       <de>DE3</de>
       <fr>DE3</fr>
       <en>EN3</en>
    </vikings>
</titles>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I am using setTextContent() to update a node value.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

/**
 * @author JayaPrasad
 * 
 */
public class ParseXml {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started XML modification");
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document xmlDoc;

            xmlDoc = docBuilder.parse(new File("sample.xml"));

            NodeList nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fr");

            for (int i = 0, length = nodes.getLength(); i < length; i ++) {
                ((Element)nodes.item(i)).setTextContent("Modified");
            }

            xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(
                    "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(xmlDoc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("sample.xml"));
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
            System.out.println("Modification Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```